# Delete different nested object if parent meets condition

Tags: json, select, key, jq

I want to delete different sub-objects from a json file (whilst maintaining the original structure) depending on whether the parent object's key meets a given condition.

Say I have:

```
{
  "A": {
    "1": {
      "bar": 1,
      "foo": 0
    }
  },
  "B": {
    "2": {
      "not_here": 0,
      "foo": 0
    },
    "3": {
      "bar": 0,
      "foo": 1
    }
  },
  "C": {
    "4": {
      "bar": 0,
      "foo": 1
    }
  }
}
```

And for all nested objects with keys in ["1", "2"], I want to delete the `bar` object, and otherwise I want to delete the `foo` object, so the output expected being:

```
{
  "A": {
    "1": {
      "foo": 0
    }
  },
  "B": {
    "2": {
      "not_here": 0,
      "foo": 0
    },
    "3": {
      "bar": 0
    }
  },
  "C": {
    "4": {
      "bar": 0
    }
  }
}
```

I would've thought this would work:

```
.[][] |= (if .key == ("1", "2") then del(.bar) else del(.foo) end)
```

But there's something wrong with my conditional I think as it just deletes `foo` everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your approach, you could write:

```
.[] |= with_entries(
   if (.key == "1" or .key == "2") 
   then .value |= del(.bar) 
   else .value |= del(.foo)
   end)
```

`with_entries` makes it easy to access each "key" and corresponding "value".

Your attempt failed because `.[][]` reaches down too deeply into the data, as you can see by running `jq '.[][]'`.  If you do, you'll see why your attempt ends up deleting the `foo` keys unconditionally, the point being that .key is only defined for you in the context of `with_entries` (though `to_entries` can be used to achieve the same effect).